# How to setup simple netcat server which sleeps before it returns a HTTP response

Tags: bash, networking, netcat, nc

*Scenario*

Whenever the `netcat` server receives a connection, I want it to sleep for 2s before returning a HTTP response.

I know we can turn netcat into a simple HTTP server by something like `nc -lp 3000 < httprespose`.

*Question*

How do I simulate the 2s delay?

Comment: is socat a completely different binary from netcat?

Comment: I don't know how you define "completely different binary". I know `socat` and `netcat` are different tools.

Comment: Thanks. Just a side question - I was trying to get good at `netcat` since it's so versatile and recommended by many people. Are there anything `netcat` can do but `socat` can't in your opinion?

Comment: I know there are things `netcat` cannot do but `socat` can. I *suspect* all things `netcat` can do, `socat` can do as well. Note there are at least two major implementations of `netcat` (aka `nc`). There is also `ncat`. See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/368155/108618).

Comment: Thanks. I know about the `different flavors of netcat` but I guess they probably provide similar functionalities. Could you cook up a solution for my problem with `socat` and put in the answer? That'd really help me and I'll be very happy to accept it right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know a way with `socat`:

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:3000,fork SYSTEM:'sleep 2; cat httprespose',pty,echo=0
```

<sup>Roughly based on my [another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/549505/108618).</sup>